# Cannot unbind a click event?

Tags: html, forms, submit, jquery

I am trying to undo an event handler/listener that is added in an linked JS file in the header of the webpage.

The basic setup:

```
<form id="form_enter_giveaway" action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="04b931caff99a0a688241e6da5f09839">
 <input type="hidden" name="enter_giveaway" value="1">
 <a href="" class="rounded view submit_entry">Enter to Win! (1P)</a>
</form>
```

JS file (http://www.steamgifts.com/js/header_functions.js):

```
$('.submit_entry, .remove_entry').click(function(){
 $('#form_enter_giveaway').submit();
 return false;
});
```

There is nothing native that should run if I click that link, and searching every reference to that link and that form in general seems to show that that single piece of JS is the only thing that could possibly be causing the form to submit.
But I have tried `$('.submit_entry, .remove_entry')` `.unbind()`, `.off()`, `die()` with the console; All with and without 'click', and every time I click that link tag it still submits. And it is interfering with the event I want to have run in its place.

Comment: I think you'll have to post more of your code.

Comment: To unbind an event the signature should be  similar to how it is bound

Comment: As far as I know there is no other code that interacts with these snippets in any way. Other than copying the entire site (steamgifts.com), I cannot think of how I could include more.

Comment: Can you point a breakpoint inside that function and debug it just to be sure its hitting that?

Comment: @Sushanth-- But, how am I not doing that already?

Comment: Ensure that your .off() call is executing after the JS file. If it is, post your code that attempts to remove the event handler.

Comment: My code is just Javascript console commands, so it definitely is executed afterwards.

Comment: Change the href="" to href="#". In Chrome the empty href seems to be posting the form.

Comment: @Mufaka Editing with the 'inspect element' editor did not show any change.
In fact I had already tried altering the anchor tab extremely and it still submits.

Comment: @Mufaka: WOW, more testing shows that you might be on to something. But, editing it post page load does not seem to fix the problem. I saved a copy of the page, and it exhibited the same problems, until I edited the link to have a `#`.
But I CANNOT edit the source, so how can I fix this bug?

Comment: Adding the `#` with JS apparently works.
@Mufaka if you wanted to type that into an Answer, I would mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var $selector = $('.submit_entry, .remove_entry');

// Binding the event using on so that it can be unbinded later
//  that triggers the submitForm handler
$selector.on('click', submitForm);

function submitForm() {
    $('#form_enter_giveaway').submit();
    return false
}

// Unbind the event using off
$selector.off('click');

// Bind the event and prevent the default action of anchor
$selector.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/A6xE4/)**

Comment: my Chrome (up to date, as far as I know) does not seem to like `on` and `off`.
I get `[object Object] has no method 'off'`.
But I will try this preventDefault();

Comment: Does not seem to have any effect, I put in an alert and it was called, but `preventDefault` did not change anything.

Comment: I have never dealt with jQuery before. Now that I think about it I am probably tying into the site's jQuery.
If that is the case, I am using 1.5.2.min

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski That's why. That version does not support `.on()` and `.off()`. please upgrade to at least jQuery `1.8`, then try this code.

Comment: If you do not want to upgrade you can use `bind` and `unbind` instead of `on` and `off`

Comment: I tried with bind/unbind, and I am not able to upgrade.
The bind/unbind showed no change.
It appeared to work, but the form still submited.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski.. Check this with `bind/unbind`  .. Seems to be working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/A6xE4/1/

Comment: I agree, and I am getting the exact same result with the `.click` function like on the original site.

It should be working, but it works differentially on the site.

But further testing, from an offline saved version of the site, revealed that the problem might not actually be the event. Like a previous person mentioned it might be the '#' missing in the link. But I am not sure how I could compensate for that post page load.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski `$('.submit_entry').attr('href', '#')`